# Silverstripe 3.1 - Can't create a new many_many relation

Tags: php, silverstripe

while extending the CsvBulkUploader to fit my needs, I cam across the problem, that Silverstripe doesn't let me create a new entry for a many_many relation.

My dataobject is `ShopItems` and has a many_many relation called `Visuals`. So in my MySQL database I get `ShopItems_Visuals`.

Now I want to create a new entry for this with the following code, and I think here's the place I made some mistake.

```
...    
    $visual = ShopItem_Visuals::create();
    $visual->ImageID = $file->ID;
    $visual->ShopItemID = $obj->ID;
    $visual->write();
...
```

after adding this to my function, I receive `Class 'ShopItem_Visuals' not found` after hitting the import button.

Is that because the database Table was created through the many_many relation in ShopItem and has no ClassName itself?

Can someone tell me how to create a new entry for this relation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there's a Class for the mapping table itself.
The entry in it should be created automagically, when adding a related Object via add.

```
$visual = new Visual();
...
$visual->write();

$ShoptItem->Visuals()->add($visual);
$ShoptItem->write();
```

If the many-many-relation name is `Visuals`, calling `->Visuals()` should return an instance of `ManyManyList` on which you can call add, remove etc.

see http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-ManyManyList.html

Comment: Solved it! Thank you. I got furious about this :D